# Prolog How to Declare a List to a Variable

Tags: list, prolog

In Prolog, I'm struggling to understand how to bind a list of lists to a variable. For instance, say I have the predicate makeList (which I don't know how to write), then I should be able to type:

```
    makeList([[0, 0], [1, 0]]).
```

Now I want to refer to [[0, 0], [1, 0]] in another predicate with a variable, ListList, like:

```
    predicateThatDoesSomething(ListList) :- write(ListList).
```

Expected Output:

```
    [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
```

Obviously predicateThatDoesSomething() knows about the variable named ListList already. But how do I make the predicate makeList()? I want to be able to type makeList([[ANY, LIST, IN, HERE], [ANOTHER, LIST]]) and have that be ListList for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a predicate that merge the two list, thus this predicate must unify with something like:

```
makeList(List1, List2, [List1, List2]).
```

After defined this predicate in you knowled base, you can interrogate the prolog engine asking:

```
makeList([1,2],[2,4],D).
```

And you'll get: `D = [[1, 2], [2, 4]]`

To make the other predicate (defined in your KB)

```
 predicateThatDoesSomething(ListList) :- write(ListList).
```

know the result (output parameter, the results of unification), you have to logically `and` the statements. So you have to ask:

```
 makeList([1,2],[2,4],D) , predicateThatDoesSomething(D).
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That is what I was looking for!